# Anagram Checker to solve the Tube Quiz

Tags: java, anagram

As you see in the title, I'm trying to code a program, which solves the "Evening Standard Tube Quiz" for me resp. one part of it. It must be able to find anagrams in tube station names. I found a lot of codes on the internet to check if two words are anagrams. But I need something different: I want to feed the program with the names of all tube stations in London and give it one anagram to compare and check, if it fits to one of the station names. How do i do that?
You see my "compare two words" code down below:

```
package anagram;

import java.util.Arrays;  

    public class anagram {  
        static void isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {  
            String s1 = str1.replaceAll("\\s", "");  
            String s2 = str2.replaceAll("\\s", "");  
            boolean status = true;  
            if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {  
                status = false;  
            } else {  
                char[] ArrayS1 = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();  
                char[] ArrayS2 = s2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();  
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS1);  
                Arrays.sort(ArrayS2);  
                status = Arrays.equals(ArrayS1, ArrayS2);  
            }  
            if (status) {  
                System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " are anagrams");  
            } else {  
                System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " are not anagrams");  
            }  
        }  

        public static void main(String[] args) {  
            isAnagram("Keep", "Peek");  
            isAnagram("Mother In Law", "Hitler Woman");  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: *"I found a lot of codes on the internet to check if two words are anagrams."* - You are doing this the wrong way.  Learning to program is not about learning to search for existing solutions on the internet.  It is about learning to write them yourself.  From scratch.

Comment: What to do you mean by "give it one anagram to compare and check" sentence? Do you want to check if an input string is anagram with any of the strings in a given list? Or do you want to check if an input list contains any two strings that are anagram of each other? If you clarify this, I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

- First build a collection of tube words, in which the characters are lowercase and sorted (e.g. `keep` --> `eekp`).
- For each candidate which you will check, do the same (e.g. `Peek` --> `eekp`) and search this in your collection.
- If found, you have found an anagram.

Example:

```
public static String orderString(String candidate) {
    char[] ccc = candidate
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}]", "")
        .toLowerCase()
        .toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(ccc);
    return String.valueOf(ccc);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Collection<String> tubeStations 
        = Arrays.asList("Acton Town", 
             "Acton Central", "Aldgate", 
             "Aldgate East", "Alperton", 
             "...");
    Map<String, String> tubeMapAnagram = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String currCandidate: tubeStations) {
        tubeMapAnagram.put(orderString(currCandidate), currCandidate);
    }
    String myCandidate = "Alpen Tor";
    String foundOriginal = tubeMapAnagram.get(orderString(myCandidate));
    if (foundOriginal!=null) {
        System.out.println("anagram found for '"+foundOriginal+"'");
    }
}
```

Even your original example could be made simpler by using the `orderString()` method.

```
boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    return Objects.equals(orderString(str1), orderString(str2));
}
```

Comment: I would prefer a `Set` over a `List`

Comment: @Lino: Sure, I would too. Therefore I referenced to "collection". TY.

Comment: Thank you, that perfectly works! Exactly what I was looking for. Now I try to understand the code, because I'm a Java beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Your code work. Do you need a way to insert all the station names in a list or what?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String[] station = {"first", "second", "third", ..., "last"};
        String check = "anagram";

     for(int i=0; i < station.length(); i++){
        isAnagram(station[i], check);  

    }  }
```